# How to get all dereferenced links of sparql query result

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web, owl

I want to download some entity profiles from dbpedia using [its sparql](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) endpoint. My query is:

```
PREFIX rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX dbpedia:   <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
select ?x where {?x rdf:type dbpedia:Drug} LIMIT 100
```

The result of above query is some links for the entity profiles. For [dereferencing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereferenceable_Uniform_Resource_Identifier) I must click on each link. I want to dereference all entity profiles and save as dataset  in my local computer. I want to use this dataset later in my project. So how I can download this entity profiles? Is there any sparql command?

Comment: why do you need to download the pages for each URL exactly? it doesnt make any sense. Also, what do you want to do in cases (happens often) that the URL is actually just a unique ID and it doesn't resolve using HTTP?

Comment: Dear @Arsham according to Linked Data Principles each url must the ability for dereferencing. I need to download all dataset for Link Descovery task. I want my task be free of network latency and some other network related problems.

Comment: In the early days of the Internet, resources were exclusively referred to by URLs (Uniform Resource Locators) and there was an expectation that a URL could be used to locate and retrieve an electronic document by means of some transfer protocol.
However, over time it became accepted that identifiers could refer to non-retrievable resources as well. The broader term URI came into use to represent an identifier for any kind of resource, including **non-information** resources.It is generally not safe to assume that a URI can be dereferenced to provide information about the resource.

Comment: As an example even though this link [link](http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person) in your result set is and `rdf:type` it is not going to give you any information about a `person`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to get all RDF data about ?x (equivalent to dereferencing all URIs) you can change your SPARQL query to:

```
 PREFIX rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
 PREFIX dbpedia:   <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
 DESCRIBE ?x where {?x rdf:type dbpedia:Drug} LIMIT 100
```

In fact, dereferencing a URI is (very often) translated into a SPARQL query by the server. The query usually has the form of:

```
 DESCRIBE <URI>
```

Comment: This will give reasonable results on most endpoints, but what `describe` queries return is not specified.  To make this robust, OP probably needs `construct where { ?s ?p ?o ; a dbpedia-owl:Drug }`.

Comment: It is true that DESCRIBE query results depend on the actual impelementation. However your proposal would return less data, because Virtuoso implementation includes also incoming links :)